# Intellij idea scala worksheet Internal error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, worksheet

I can't define function in scala worksheet in Intelijj IDEA. Also worksheet doesn't show anything when in repl run type - I have to switch to plain run type. I can define for example variables in worksheet. When I run scala repl from terminal I can define function as expected.

Running on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using Intelijj IDEA 2019.1.3, I've installed Java JDK 8.0_221 (with instructions from https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-manually-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-16-04 page) and scala 2.13.0 from .deb package from scala page.

in a worksheet:

```
def max(x: Int, y: Int): Int =  {
  if(x > y) x 
  else y
}
```

Expected:
function max is defined

Actual result:

```
Internal error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ClientEventProcessor.process(ClientEventProcessor.scala:22)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:47)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.handle$(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:37)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.handle(RemoteServerRunner.scala:16)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$5(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:30)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$5$adapted(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$3(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:29)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$3$adapted(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$2(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:25)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.$anonfun$send$2$adapted(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:21)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:24)
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner.send$(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:22)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner.send(RemoteServerRunner.scala:16)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(RemoteServerRunner.scala:36)
scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:155)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.RemoteServerRunner$$anon$1.run(RemoteServerRunner.scala:32)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.server.RemoteServerConnector.compileAndRun(RemoteServerConnector.scala:111)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.processor.WorksheetCompiler$$anon$3.run(WorksheetCompiler.scala:61)
com.intellij.compiler.progress.CompilerTask.run(CompilerTask.java:185)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:731)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:586)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:86)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:311)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had same problem with scala 2.13.0 and wasted a lot of time to find correct advice. Then I changed Global Libraries to scala-sdk-2.12.7, now everything works correct in REPL.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed the suggestion proposed in [this recent post](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16277) in the JetBrains issue tracker, where the solution is to set the compile server to JDK 11 (or later).